# invalid merchant configuration in wirecard

Tags: php

I am integrating wirecard payment gateway in my website 
When I am clicking on checkout button and  putting valid card details then is showing **Invalid merchant configuration**  and in merchant account dashboard, that same transactions is shown with the error of '242 terminal is not ready with transaction fail status. Can any one please help me out

Answer (score 1):

An **Invalid merchant configuration** (errorCode: 30002) usually means that the configuration of your account on Wirecard side or the transaction status somehow doesn't fit to what you are trying to do and can have different reasons. You sould have received more information by the Wirecard response, normally via parameters like error.1.message, error.1.paySysMessage,..

Try to use the [demo mode](https://guides.wirecard.com/wcp:demo_mode) or [test mode](https://guides.wirecard.com/wcp:test_mode) to ensure the functionality of your implementation. If that works, you will have to call the wirecard support - they have to identify the merchant configuration problem with your transactions.